# Error using primefaces 3.5 LazyDataModel in Jboss 7.1.3

Tags: primefaces, jboss7.x

First of all here's my setup:

1.) jboss7.1.3

2.) maven javaee6 generated project

3.) ear, war, ejb project format

4.) java 7

I'm trying to create a DataTable component using LazyDataModel as the source, but can't get around the following issue:

```
22:28:56,419 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-6) Failed to define class org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel in Module "deployment.dropship-ear.ear:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/primefaces/model/LazyDataModel (Module "deployment.dropship-ear.ear:main" from Service Module Loader)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/model/DataModel
```

What I tried so far were (both didn't work):

1.) Add primefaces dependency in ejb project, scope=compile

2.) Add primefaces module in jboss7.1.3 and add dependency to both ejb and war project, scope=compile|provided

Note that I have defined jboss jsf-api in both web and ejb project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solved this issue by adding jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

Add primefaces dependency in ejb/pom.xml and exclude it in war/pom.xml as explained in this link: http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-use-primefaces-with-jboss-713.html